# Python - How to back to beginning while when is error

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have problem with while.

```
Code:
(...)
if a == "1":

            file = open("abc.txt", "a")

            rep = int(input("write rep \n"))
            while rep >= 1:
                    rep = rep - 1
                    print("rep nr:")
                    print(rep + 1)
                    try:
                       / do something/
                    except:      #if error
                           /do something again /
                    continue
```

when i use "continue" script start again from "except" point. I need to start from "try:" when everything is OK. if not start again from except.
How i can do this correctly?

Comment: `continue` at the very end of the `while` loop is useless. You will continue with the next iteration of the `while` loop anyway. So, things probably don't happen the way you tell us...

Answer (score 0):

Yes its true.
continue back me to the start .
I had a mistake in my code (/do something)
error was at first line so script going to except: point every time.

Thanks for your help.